# Change gateway sequence with network manager

Tags: networking

My computer has 2 ethernet ports and 1 wireless port. One of the ethernet ports (eth5) and the wireless port (wlan0) are both configured to connect to a network server, and the other ethernet port (eth4) is configured to connect to a local network switch for communicating with some local devices. The route table of the computer looks like this (as I can not post image yet):

Destination  Gateway      Genmask        Iface 
0.0.0.0      141.21.32.1  0.0.0.0        eth5  
10.10.10.0   0.0.0.0      255.255.255.0  eth4  
141.21.12.0  0.0.0.0      255.255.252.0  wlan0 
141.21.32.0  0.0.0.0      255.255.224.0  eth5  
169.254.0.0  0.0.0.0      255.255.0.0    eth5

My question is that, how I could change the sequence of the gateways with the network-manager in ubuntu (permanently), so that the gateway of wlan0 will be used before the eth4's. Otherwise when I unplug the cable from eth5, I will lose connection to the network (the gateway of eth4 will be used by default).

I tried editing the /etc/network/interfaces file, but it conflicts with the network-manager, and it can not handle the dynamic events (e.g., when network cable is plugged or unplugged), meaning that its settings are static, while the network-manager can handle these things perfectly, and change the network configurations adaptively, so I would like to find a solution for this problem with network-manager.

The os is ubuntu 13.04 32bit. Thanks for viewing and I will appreciate for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved by checking the option "use this connection only for resources on its network" in the "Routes" page of the IPv4 settings of the configuration interface for the local network (used by eth4) in network-manager.